# Adding a custom field in Membership Provider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I'm using Membership Provider in my ASP.NET MVC Application . I want to check a user is admin or not .

```
if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
    {
          ....
    }
```

ValidateUser gets only Username and Password , I want to add another field ( IsAdmin ) . how can I write this code ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jsalvy reminded me, you can just do this:

```
bool isUserAdmin = IsUserInRole(userName, "Admin");
```

The `IsUserInRole` will return true if the user is in the role or false if not. You can also use `string[] userRoles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(userName);` to get all the roles a user is in. And you can use the `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]` attribute to restrict access to anyone who is not an admin.

Answer (score 0):

This should be done with an implementation of the RoleProvider, not the MembershipProvider, as the MembershipProvider does not handle permissions/roles.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74.aspx  is a brief overview of the RoleProvider base class. As you can see it contains methods like 'IsUserInRole' that allow you to check things like this.

Here's a more in-depth sample of how to implement it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/317sza4k.aspx

Aside from that, you can always create a MembershipManager class of some sort that directly checks against your DataSource whether a given user is or is not a member.

**Edit:** I wanted to clarify that you do not need to implement a provider on top of the RoleProvider with the standard setup.NET Membership/Role/Profile model. If you have roles setup for the users, you can access them with the [Roles Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.aspx).  The Roles class is to the RoleProvider, what the Membership class is to the MembershipProvider.

Answer (score 0):

It's simply User.IsInRole("Administrators")

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprincipal.isinrole.aspx